# Background image inside DIV not showing up?

Tags: image, html

well, here's the issue, I have created a div with a class and in the css I give this div a background image but for some reason it will not show up. Here's the code;

HTML:

```
<div class="stat"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.stat {
background-image: url(../img/stat.png);
width: 430;
height: 344;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the url is correct? Maybe it's `url('img/stat.png');`

Comment: Yes, the url is correct, the folder 'img' is located on the main directory that's why I have written it out like '../img/stat.png'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
.stat {
background-image: url(../img/stat.png);
width: 430px;
height: 344px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I can't believe I made such a silly mistake! Thanks again!

Comment: @Cwtch22 Just please click on "This answer is useful" to close this question, thank you.